# Swift: Cast Any or AnyObject to JSON

Tags: json, swift

I want to wrap data to JSON before sending.

```
func request(content: [String]) {
        
        try? JSONEncoder().encode(content)
```

This worked well when sending arrays of string. However, I would also like to send other structures that can be represented in JSON.

For example arrays containing arrays, or dictionaries.

My idea was to make it

```
func request(content: Any) {
        
        try? JSONEncoder().encode(content)
```

Which gives `Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Encodable'`

How can I make the parameter as generic as possible so what can be formed as JSON gets formed as JSON and whatever fails, fails? I do understand I can't JSONify everything but I would like to be able to do it with things that I know of can be represented in JSON form. I found things like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471720/2161301 but apparently you can't do that on "normal" functions

Comment: what do you mean by normal functions? The solution mentioned in the link you shared is the way to achieve what you are looking for. i.e. func request<T: Encodable>(content: T) {}

Comment: what problem are you facing with this approach?

Comment: Hey @waseemwk thank you for the example. One situation where it's not working is `let arr = ["a", ["b", "c"]] as [Any]`, then I get `Protocol 'Any' as a type cannot conform to 'Encodable'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AnyCodable`](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable) in your project.

Then you will be allowed to use `[String: AnyEncodable]` / `[AnyEncodable]` etc. in the places where you are not able to use `Any` while trying to use `JSONEncoder` api.

Comment: That looks very interesting, thank you! I haven't verified yet but going to bed soon so I will tick :)

Comment: `AnyCodable` it's define by xcode environment or separately ?

Comment: @jatinfl It's a 3rd party library. There's a link in the answer.

Comment: yeah i see that so i asked it will be provide by Xcode. anyway thanks :)

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038083/1187415